# Камера не следит за появившемся префабом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим, скрипт находит центральную точку между двумя объектами на карте.

> `public List<Transform> targets;`

```
Vector3 GetCenterPoint()
{
    if (targets.Count == 1)
    {
        return targets[0].position;
    }

    var bounds = new Bounds(targets[0].position, Vector3.zero);
    for (int i=0; i < targets.Count; i++)
    {
        bounds.Encapsulate(targets[i].position);
    }

    return bounds.center;
}
```

Но как сделать нахождение центра между объектами, если они только появились на карте? 
Способ создания префаба на карту:

```
if (!spawned)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            spawned = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: очевидно нужно обновить значения ` targets` после создания объекта..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо вам нужно при создании нового объекта, добавлять его в ваш лист `targets`. Сделать это можно так:

```
if (!spawned)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            var newTarget = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            targets.Add(newTarget.transform);
            spawned = true;
        }
    }
```

Таким образом, все заспавненные объекты будут учитываться при получении центральной точки в методе, что вы написали выше.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а как можно будет потом удалить из списка?

Comment: У меня есть пустой объект в точке (0, 0, 0), внутри объекта находятся Canvas и модель танка. Камера следит за пустым объектом (который не перемещается). Как сделать так, чтобы камера следила за моделью танка?

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов , удалить объект из листа можно так: targets.Remove(**ваш_объект**);

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов , чтобы камера следила за дочерним объектом, т.е. в вашем случае за танком, очевидно, что вам нужно передать камере не родительский объект (пустой недвигающийся объект), а именно сам танк. Если добавите больше кода, возможно я смогу помочь.

Comment: ну вот по вашему скрипту создаётся префаб (пустой объект) и сразу заносится в список отслеживаемых объектов. Как создать родительский объект, но отслеживать модель, которая находится внутри него?

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов если на вашей модели есть какой-нибудь скрипт, отличающий модель танка от других дочерних в этом "пустом", как вы говорите, объекте, то можно сначала найти этот объект внутри созданного родительского так: `var tankModel = newTarget.GetComponentsInChildren<**скрипт_на_танке**>();`
`if (tankModel != null) targets.Add(tankModel);//это нужно для тех объектов, у которых нет внутри никакого танка`

Проблема в том, что это, наверное, частный случай, применимый лишь к танку, а для остальных заспавненных объектов, камера должна следить за ними самими, а не искать какие-то дочерние.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92960/discussion-between-mikhail-deyman-and--).